# I would like a button that leverage the AAA graphics

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**I EXPECT FOR MY ENGLISH, BUT I AM USING GOOGLE TRANSLATOR**

hi I'm creating a multiplayer game I put the graphics AAA, among these I put the component PostProcessingBehaviour, on the UI menu I made, on the graphics settings, I would like with a button to disable all the components that I put on the camera to make the graphics AAA , for less powerful PCs, so they can play all, to give me an example even to disable the PostProcessingBehaviour via a UI button, then I tried to use onclick, put the camera and put on the "bool enable" works but the game is online , and then it does not work, but if it was offline my problem was solved enough to use the button ui, but with the online I can not of course, what script I could use, the script will have to put on the UI button and disable the script component in this PostProcessingBehaviour case,
how can I do? do you recommend a script? I have little experience and I'm learning, I would need this thing, thanks in advance

**IN SHORT WORDS**

I would like to know a script that disables the PostProcessingBehaviour component or script from the "camera" object

use language c#
use unity 3d

Comment: So if I am understanding correctly,  You have an online game, and in it you have a graphics menu,  You want to be able to disable Special effects such as PostProcessingEffects with the click of a button?  If you do this offline(So without multiplayer support) it works, but if you are online it doesn't work?  If that is the case it sounds like your camera and postprocessingeffects are being created on the server, when they should only be created once on the client side, the server shouldnt even know about them.

Comment: @Eddge you understand perfectly, in what sense "client side"?

Comment: What framework are you using for your networking?  Proton? UNET?

Comment: @Eddge use photon network for unity 3d